# How to set a timeout inside a promise chain's .then()

Tags: javascript, promise, settimeout

I have a promise chain that executes in order. But I want to delay one of them and not have the other ones execute until the delayed one is done. How do I accomplish this? I tried a setTimeOut but seems like promise chain is async so the timeout did not work as expected.

```
var p = Promise.resolve("Hello");

p.then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
  console.log("========== Then Block 1");
  return "how are you";
}).then((result)=>{
  console.log(result);
  console.log("========== Then Block 2");
  return "I'm Fine! Thank you"
}).then((result) => {

  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("Time out Done!");
  }, 3000);

  console.log(result);
  console.log("========== Then Block 3");
}).then(()=>{
  console.log("========== Then Block 4");
})
```

This prints:

```
"Hello"
"========== Then Block 1"
"how are you"
"========== Then Block 2"
"I'm Fine! Thank you"
"========== Then Block 3"
"========== Then Block 4"
"Time out Done!"
```

What I want instead is:

```
"Hello"
"========== Then Block 1"
"how are you"
"========== Then Block 2"
"I'm Fine! Thank you"
"Time out Done!"
"========== Then Block 3"
"========== Then Block 4"
```

Comment: setTimeout is asynchronous itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new promise, and resolve it inside of `setTimeout` callback:

```
Promise
  .resolve("Hello")
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    console.log("========== Then Block 1");
    return "how are you";
  })
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result);
    console.log("========== Then Block 2");
    return "I'm Fine! Thank you";
  })
  .then(result => new Promise(resolve => { // <== create a promise here
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("Time out Done!");
      console.log(result);
      console.log("========== Then Block 3");
      resolve(); // <== resolve it in callback
    }, 3000);
  }))
  .then(() => {
    console.log("========== Then Block 4");
  });
```